# Separate indented hierarchy list into columns based on parent member

Tags: vba

I have the below mentioned INPUT and I want to get the output as shared below under output header.

In my INPUT data in my column A contains the data which has different indenting level.

Basically the code should run on this range and check for the highest level of indenting and for each highest level of indenting it should put it under "Mapping 1" header and its subsequent lower levels in Mapping 2, 3 and 4.

[image: INPUT]

OUTPUT:
[image]

I have developed a code which is giving me error on the below mentioned line:
Run Time error 1004:

```
    If currVal > arr(i, 3) Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(k, arr(i, 3) - 1).Value = arr(i, 1)
        End If
```

Overall Code:-

```
Sub transposerowcolmulti()

 Dim arr(1 To 8, 0 To 3) As Variant
 Dim i As Long, j As Long

 ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Input").Activate

 For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)

        arr(i, 1) = range("A6").Offset(i, 0).Value
        arr(i, 2) = IsBold(range("A6").Offset(i, 0))
        arr(i, 3) = Level(range("A6").Offset(i, 0))

        Next i
 Dim k As Long, l As Long
       Dim prevVal As Long, currVal As Long


    k = 0
    l = 0

        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
        For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)

            If l = 0 Then
                currVal = arr(i, 3)
                l = l + 1
            End If

            If currVal = arr(i, 3) Then
                ActiveCell.Offset(k, currVal - 1).Value = arr(i, 1)
                End If

            If currVal > arr(i, 3) Then
                ActiveCell.Offset(k, arr(i, 3) - 1).Value = arr(i, 1)
                End If

            If currVal < arr(i, 3) Then
                ActiveCell.Offset(k, arr(i, 3) - 1).Value = arr(i, 1)
                End If

             currVal = arr(i, 3)
             k = i
                Next i


End Sub

Function Level(Optional cCell As range)
' LEVEL returns the outline level of the current row. It will not automatically update and therefore
'   a recalculation Ctrl-Alt-F9 is required.

    If cCell Is Nothing Then
        Set cCell = Application.Caller
    End If
    Level = cCell.Rows.IndentLevel

End Function

Function IsBold(ByVal Cell As range) As Boolean

IsBold = Cell.Font.Bold

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't get how exactly the code should work, I'm pretty sure that your runtime error comes from the fact that you access `ActiveCell`. You add a new Worksheet (which gets the activesheet) and `ActiveCell` is set to `A1`of this sheet. In the first iteration of the 2nd loop. `currVal` is 0, the term `ActiveCell.Offset(k, currVal - 1)` is `ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1)` and this causes the runtime error as you are in column 1 - no offset -1 possible.

Strong advice: Don't use `ActiveSheet`, `ActiveCell` or `Select`as they can cause significant performance issues and are more difficult to debug.

Comment: Any suggestion as to how should I change this line

Comment: Is my code incorrect will it not yield the output which I shared . My concept behind this code is to create a two dimensional array and then transpose the data from rows to columns based on indentation.

Comment: Please suggest me to modify this code to give the required results